# How to get selected value from database in combo box

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to get selected value in combo box from database .Here is my code but when i used this code it is selecting just "write" from option in every combo box and does not consider if conditions which i used in options.

```
success:function(data){
    $(".modules").empty();
    $(".modules").append("<option value='0'>-Select-</option>");
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
        console.log(data[i]);
        $('.modules').eq(i).append("<option value='n' if(data[i].name=='none') selected='selected' >none</option>");
        $('.modules').eq(i).append("<option value='w'  if(data[i].name=='write') selected='selected' >write</option>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Please separate your long, long sentence into small ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
success:function(data){
    $(".modules").empty();
    $(".modules").append("<option value='0'>-Select-</option>");
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
        console.log(data[i]);
        if(data[i].name=='none'){
            $('.modules').eq(i).append("<option value='n' selected='selected' >none</option>");
        }else{
            if(data[i].name=='write'){
                $('.modules').eq(i).append("<option value='w'   selected='selected' >write</option>");
            } 
        }
    });
}
```